# Modern Compilers Inlining Across Cpp Files and PImpl Idiom Overhead

Tags: c++, performance, inline, compiler-optimization, pimpl-idiom

I was taught that in general practice its best not to try to beat the compiler, at least until its proven to be stupid. So in general, and since its only used as a hint anyways, the inline tag has never been a priority for me to use because I was taught that the compiler is pretty good when it comes to understanding the trade offs your system will have to make when it comes to inlining vs. looped calls to a function pointer for example.

But then I just read recently that functions cannot be inlined unless they are defined in the header file because otherwise the compiler won't see it when it starts to work on other header and cpp files (read from . I did some more research and I found that some people were saying that this is the old way things worked and that modern compilers perform "Whole Program Optimization" or "Link-Time Code Generation" which is responsible for the construction of the obj files that I'm used to seeing which can then be linked together and optimized further such as allowing the compiler to see functions in the obj file that were once "hidden" in the cpp file and then inline optimize them where appropriate. This sounds great but I'm wondering which source to trust and was wondering if I could get an additional opinion on the matter.

Further research lead me to a deeper understanding of the Pimpl idiom and why it is used, most obviously to save on compile time costs and increase readability and stability, but as I continued reading I noticed that the [cppreference.com/cpp/pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) documentation states that separating header information from implementation details can lead to runtime overhead as calls made to functions require at least one level of indirection in addition to increased spacial cost due to the additional pointers used. So if I was to create a real time application where runtime performance is high priority is it best to avoid the Pimpl idiom and if so should I instead use their suggested alternative and tag all functions inline and place them in the header file (if I'm understanding their suggested alternative correctly), or is their an alternative to that such as only using cpp files without causing lnk2005 errors that I'm not seeing (maybe only using one large cpp file).

Thanks for the help in advance I know it was a bit of a text crawl to get to this point.

Comment: `inline` is not a hint for the compiler to inline function calls. It has nothing to do with (it is instead related to the "one definition rule"), it's one of the biggest misconceptions about the `inline` keyword in C++. And many static analyzers will in fact print information messages about redundant `inline` specifiers

Comment: And when it comes to performance the most important rule is always: Measure, measure, measure. Do not try to optimize code that you don't even know is slow (or causes performance issues for your applicatoin)

Comment: Do you have Link-Time Code Generation enabled?

Comment: Using pimple idiom is more or less a nightmare in my eyes! You start doing the things a compiler already knows better. And coding all the handcrafted indirection is not a fun. And yes, it breaks optimizing the code. But before you start thinking about run time overhead/costs of any thing, watch out for good algorithms! Start coding, MEASURE, MEASURE, MEASURE! Compilers are much better as people think! Always!? NO, especially for small embedded targets some compilers are horrible bad. gcc for avr ist very bad! On x86 gcc is really doing a good job.

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm not sure exactly how 'inline' enforces the one definition rule. But I am aware that defining a function in the header file can lead to linker errors if its be defined or included elsewhere unless it has the inline tag, which thinking on in now I guess is because it reproduces the code inline every time, but that makes me think that the compiler doesn't ever choose not to inline once you have specified it. As for the measuring guideline, I know but I would like to increase my knowledge of the theory as well as add another potential tool to solve a problem in the future.

Comment: @user253751 yes I have discovered how to enable the flags with visual studio

Comment: @Klaus, if the pimpl idiom is such a nightmare then how do you get around it, do you just contain all of your applications code in a single cpp file?

Comment: I just realized I think I might be confusing the pimpl idiom with the act of separating header declarations from class implementations. I think the pimpl idiom is slightly more complex. What I meant for consideration was if simple separation of header declaration from class implementation would cost runtime performance or prevent the compiler from doing its job properly. If someone could confirm that I am indeed confusing the pimpl idiom with another technique thats name escapes me I will gladly edit the question to reflect my error

Comment: "do you just contain all of your applications code in a single cpp file" ??? That is the opposite what I want! Simply implement your classes and if there is no cyclic dependency more or less all member functions can reside in the header. BTW: C++ is moving a lot in direction to MTP so a lot of stuff is done in compile time today. constexpr/consteval, constexpr if, compile time data types with user defined types as template args and so on. Today we can do all algorithms with constant data in compile time, so do it!

Comment: @Klaus I just read up on the header only approach which seems a lot less unnecessarily complicated and saves you a lot of time when it comes to retyping all of the functions in the implementations files and I do like the idea of being able to make liberal use of template meta programming and crunching more data at compile time. So as long as you avoid cyclical references there should be no penalty from opting out of using implementation files?

Comment: The only bad thing on using the "all in the header" idiom is, that compile time increases, as on every translation unit all headers must be parsed again. But that is nothing I fear for, as my machine has enough power. You can also use LTO and write all in cpp files and let the linker resolve all the things.It is more or less matter of taste. As I use more or less template only code, all must be in the header, so i personally have no option.Why I use more or less only templated code? I use CRTP as a general approach for nearly all.That keeps me all benefit of fast composing and speedy binaries.

Comment: @Klaus I think you've definitely convinced me! I just read up on LTO and learned that since the program has already been translated into machine code it makes it difficult to further optimize. I am curious to find out if large real time applications such as game engines use the header only approach given that compilation time may be a constraint. Plus I used a little CRTP before and loved it but have since moved to entity-component systems and haven't needed to implement indirection free template virtual functions lately but would love to get into some more template meta programming magic!